# Change of Basis Matrix and repeated composition.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations, change-of-basis

[image]

Hi I was wondering if anyone could help me with part d) e) and f) of this linear algebra question.

So far I have found:

a) $T(x^2 - 2x + 1)= 3x^2 - 5x - 1$ using linear map definitions.

b) the associated matrix $A$ is:

$A= 
    \begin{pmatrix}
    -1 & 0 & 0\\
    -2 & 2 & 1 \\
    2 & 0 & 1 \\
    \end{pmatrix}
$

c) used the fact that the dimension is equal to 3 and have proven they are linearly independent by showing that $C_o=C_1=C_2=0$.

And here is where i get stuck. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

d)

$$\mathcal{C}=\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 0 & -1 & 1 \\
 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 1 & 1 & -1 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$
$$\mathcal{C}\cdot \mathcal{B}=(x^2-x,x,-x^2+x+1)$$
$$\mathcal{C}^{-1}=\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 1 & 0 & 1 \\
 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 1 & 1 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$
$$\mathcal{C}^{-1}\cdot (x^2-x,x,-x^2+x+1)=(1,x,x^2)$$

Comment: Thanks, could you explain how you obtained the matrix C please?

Comment: @Taylor Rows of $\mathcal{C}$ are the components of the base $(-x + x^2, x, 1 + x - x^2)$ in the base $\mathcal{B}$. $0\cdot 1+ (-1)\cdot x+1\cdot x^2=-x+x^2$ and so on

Comment: Okay thanks. I'm just a bit confused as I thought that it was meant to be the columns that represent the components of the base.